# Problem "F5" Debugging ASP.NET Web Application Project with VS2008 on Vista

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, debugging, windows-vista

Greetings!

I'm working with a .NET3.5 Web Application project in Visual Studio 2008 on Vista Ultimate.  I'd rather use IIS7 than Cassini as my local test web server.  I have the website setup in II7 and every thing is served with no problems.

However, I'd like to use the VS debugger hooked up to F5 instead of manually attaching to the process.  So in my HOSTS file, I have:

```
127.0.0.1   mysite.com
```

In my website project's "Web" settings, I have:

- "Use Local IIS Web server" is selected
- Project Url is "http://mysite.com"
- Override application root URL is "http://mysite.com"

Also, in IIS, I've bound mysite.com to 127.0.0.1 on port 80.  In addition, the account used to run the IIS server is a member of the Administrators group and I run VS2008 as Administrator.

However, starting my project with debugging yields this error:

**Unable to start debugging on the web server.  The IIS worker process for the launched URL is not currently running.**

Any ideas why I can't get VS debugging to work with IIS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved.  Instead of binding to 127.0.0.1, I changed it to "All Unassigned" and I'm back in business :)

Answer (score 0):

> We fixed it by replacing "::1
>   localhost" by "127.0.0.1 localhost" in
>   the hosts file.

Found this in the ASP.Net Forums:
http://forums.asp.net/t/1394972.aspx

Not sure it will help but worth a try...

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately the problem still remains.

Comment: Sorry, I am out of ideas, hopefully some one is smarter than both of us in this area?  good luck~